# Why the path is incorrect with gulp and browser-sync

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

This is my code with gulp and browser-sync
[image]

Now, why the error of this path:
[image]

the current directory structure is this:

[image]

and the css style:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style is in the `tmp/styles` folder. When your css url is set to `./images/landing.jpg`, that single dot simply means to look in the current folder. So BrowserSync does exactly what you ask and looks for an images folder inside of the styles folder. So, it's your CSS that is wrong, not BrowserSync.

What you actually want is to back out to the parent directory of the styles folder, and look for an images folder there, which is accomplished with **two** periods:

`background: url("../images/landing.jpg") no-repeat center;`